# TypeError: dataOne.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have problem about Map method in JavaScript.
I'm using React Hooks.
I got error when I executed this code.
I tried to refer to JavaScript documents but It doesn't work.
I just would like to show my JSON data to h1.
I think it's easy question but I don't know how to fix.
I think it is easy question but
Please tell me if you know.

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import { Table } from "./components/Table";
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'



const App = () => (

  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={ShowTable} />
      <Route exact path="/edit/:id" component={Edit} />
    </div>

  </BrowserRouter>


);

const ShowTable = () => {

  return (
    <div>
      <Table />
    </div>
  );
}

const Edit = props => {

  const id = props.match.params.id;
  const [dataOne, setDataOne] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8080/action/edit/" + id).then((response) =>
      setDataOne(response.data)
    )
  }, [])

  console.log(dataOne);

  return (
    <div>
      {
        dataOne.map(data => (
          <h1>{dataOne.listNo}</h1>
        ))
      }

    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

[image]

This is object.

Comment: are you sure that your endpoint `http://localhost:8080/action/edit/" + id` returns an array?

Comment: `setDataOne([...dataOne, ...response.data])` will this work?

Comment: Please check the data type for the `response.data` before setting the state.

Comment: You seem to be trying to use dataOne as both an object (`dataOne.listNo`) and an array. (`dataOne.map()`). It seems like your endpoint is returning an object and not an array

Comment: >> Germa Vinsmoke
I got iterable error when I chenged code.

Comment: >> Nick Parsons  Yes, I got Json data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your remote data looks like just a literal object which isn't an array so you just set your state as literal object & no longer have to use `map` function which is only a prototype function for array.

```js
const [dataOne, setDataOne] = useState({});

return (
  <div>
    <h1>{dataOne.listNo}</h1>
  </div>
)
```